# WCF REST starter kit fails to install

Tags: wcf, rest

I just, quite anxiously, downloaded the spankin new WCF REST starter kit. The installed failed. Anyone else had this problem?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx

Edit: The install fails during the template installation. The VS JIT debugger window pops up. Nothing else is running the PC, I am running as an admin on XP Pro, and the error occurs from either the EXE or the MSI.

Comment: How did it fail?  What step?  Error messages?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it just failed for me too.  Got a warning about replacing an existing file during the template install, then a hard crash after I told it to continue.

EDIT: Just tried again - it worked.  Did 3 things different:

- Closed all running VS2008 SP1 instances
- Read the install guide closer and chose to run setup.exe instead of the msi, and did "Run As Administrator"
- Didn't close the MSI installer until the delayed template installer had completed.

Here's the Install Guide:

---

SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS:

1. Windows Vista OR Windows Server 2008 OR Windows Server 2003
2. Visual Studio 2008 SP1

---

INSTALL AND USAGE STEPS:

1. Before installing, remember to uninstall any versions you have installed on the machine (see the Uninstall section below for steps to uninstall).
2. Run the setup.exe in administrator mode (right click on setup.exe and select 'Run as Administrator')
3. The install process will launch a visual studio installer. Remember to click through the visual studio installer to install the templates. NOTE: You may miss the vsi that is launched, so be sure to finish both the vsi and setup.exe installs to ensure that the whole install process is complete.
4. While running the vsi, you will get a prompt, which you can safely accept to continue.
5. Once installed, build the Microsoft.ServiceModel.web project installed on your machine.
6. You need to reference the Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.dll assembly from the template generated projects, as well as from the samples. Please remember to verify this while using your templates and projects.
   Note that you may also use a project reference instead.
7. There is a solution that includes all the samples provided in the "WCF REST Starter Kit\Samples\WCF REST Starter Kit Samples" location. This gives you a way to easily try out all the samples from one place.